# Getting IP addresses from known MAC addresses from server side

Tags: python, django, networking, ip

I have a server that has list of MAC addresses of devices (think IOT devices). Is it possible to get their IP addresses? Devices with these MAC addresses are in same network like the client (through simple web interface) sending requests to server.

I am aware that this question maybe a little vague, but I will edit it with any new information I get.

I am using python (Django framework) for server.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `ARP table`:

```
Internet Address    Physical address    Type
220.0.0.160         00-50-04-62-F7-23   static
```

It's used to "convert" IPs to MACs

[Here's](http://homework.nwsnet.de/releases/9577/) an example how you could to do it in Python.